# Entity Framework property has value when not requested

Tags: .net, entity-framework, linq, ef-code-first

The below code should pull just the `event`, `sport` and `event parent` however it is also pulling `divisions`.  We do call the divisionsRepository before this happens but I have never seent his before. Does it take what is in the context, `divisions`, and assign it to new data that comes in afterwards?  I want to cache this object, but not with `Divisions`.

```
 var includes = new List<Expression<Func<Event, object>>>
                {
                    q => q.Sport,
                    q => q.EventParent
                };

                var test = _eventsRepository.Get(includes.ToArray(), q => q.Id == eventId);
```

Comment: Your question contains way to less information to help you, sorry

Comment: I understand but what else would you need?  I am making a query call that grabs Divisions before this method.  Then once this method is called it also has the divisions even though I didnt request them.  After 8+ years is this how EF always worked?